# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test in Scipy with non-normalized data

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to test whether a list of values is uniformly distributed. I know the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is the proper test to run. However, My results don't make any sense to me.

In the code below, I create two lists of values, x which is uniformly distributed, and y which is not uniformly distributed.

**What should happen:**
I run scipy's kstest() on both x and y, and the p-value for x passes, the p-value for y does not pass.

**What is happening:**
I run scipy's kstest() on both x and y, and the p-value is 0.0 for both x and y.

```
In [1]:

from scipy import stats
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
In [2]:

x = np.random.uniform(size=1000)
sigma_x = np.std(x)
mean_x = x.mean()

plt.hist(x)
plt.show()

In [3]:

y = x**4
sigma_y = np.std(y)
mean_y = y.mean()

plt.hist(y)
plt.show()

In [4]:

stats.kstest(x, 'uniform', args=(mean_x,sigma_x))
Out[4]:
(0.499, 0.0)
In [5]:

stats.kstest(y, 'uniform', args=(mean_y,sigma_y))
Out[5]:
(0.67400000000000004, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing the `args` argument. It isn't always the desired mean and standard deviation, it's whatever arguments the distribution you're using takes. In this case, [`stats.uniform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.uniform.html) takes two arguments, `loc` and `scale`, and it "is constant between `loc` and `loc + scale`."

So you don't want to use the mean and standard deviation. Instead you want the min and max of what the uniform distribution is defined over, `args=(0, 1)` if you want to test against a known uniform distribution, or `args=(min(x), max(x))` if you want to use the sample estimates.

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(size=1000)
y = x**4

stats.kstest(x, 'uniform', args=(0, 1))
# (0.029538499688200326, 0.34247911001793319)

stats.kstest(y, 'uniform', args=c(0, 1))
# (0.50121963249814794, 0.0)
```